# Use with the scanf function

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, scanf

I am making a scanf countdown via objective-C, so the program will count down from what ever number you input. However, there's an annoying semantic error in the code saying:Data argument not used by format string. Also the program doesn't countdown, it just displays the output as zero once I input a number.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        int x,number;

        NSLog(@"please enter a number:");
        scanf("i", &number);
        for (x = number;  x>=0; x--)
            NSLog(@"%i",x);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: hey for int, we use `scanf("%d", *)` in c!

Comment: hey and in if statement it is `y%x` which i think should be `y/x`

Comment: if (y%x==0.0) with floats is not a good idea since floats do not have exact representation, it is better to use ints.

Answer (score 4):

You don't say what trouble you are having, or what you've tried to sort it out, so folks will have a hard time helping you.

But for starters the code fragment you've posted (a) never gives `y` a value and (b) the loop will never execute as you set `count = 1` and then test for `count == 3` - which will fail immediately and not enter the loop.

For (a) I could only guess where you expect `y` to come from, for (b) you probably meant `count <= 3` - i.e. loop 3 times?

**Addendum after comment**

OK, let's re-write your code a little and add some comments. A `for` loop can be rewritten as a `while` loop, in your case this would look like:

```
count = 1; // initialize
while (count == 3) // Test, will fail immediately, did you mean count <= 3?
{
   NSLog(@"enter a number");
   scanf("%i", &x);
   // At this point you have set x to a value
   // however y has no value - as it is a local variable it has some random value
   // the next line calculates `y%x`, and without a value for y this calculation
   // is meaningless. Did you mean to read in both x and y? E.g. scanf("%i%i", &x, &y)?
   // Note you should also check the return value from scanf, it is the number of items
   // successfully converted - while you may "enter a number" your user might type
   // "sixteen", which is a number to them but scanf won't parse it with %i!
   if (y%x == 0)
      NSLog(@"%i is evenly divisible by %i", y, x);
   else
      NSLog(@"%i is NOT evenly divisible by %i", y, x);

   count++; // increment
}
```

Making the changes above and reverting to the `for` gives:

```
for (count = 1; count <= 3; count++)
{
   NSLog(@"enter two numbers");
   int numberRead = scanf("%i%i", &x, &y);

   if (numberRead != 2)
      NSLog(@"error, unable to parse two numbers");
   else if (y%x == 0)
      NSLog(@"%i is evenly divisible by %i", y, x);
   else
      NSLog(@"%i is NOT evenly divisible by %i", y, x);
}
```

HTH

Comment: could you say that differently, I didn't quite understand that

Comment: @user1706978 - I've added an addendum to the answer

Comment: @user1706978 - ?? Something more than a smidgen and less than everything.

Answer (score 2):

your scanf syntax is wrong it should be

```
scanf("%i",&number) //for integer
```